# exclude duplicate URL variable from RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi im using this code to rewrite the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^m-(.*)/(.*)$ ?til=data&id_data=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

If i go to `http://www.domain.com/m-200/test-title`

**RESULT GET:**

`Array ( [til] => data [id_data] => 200 [title] => test-title )`

but if i go to `http://www.domain.com/m-200/m-200/test-title`

**RESULT GET:**

```
Array ( [til] => data [id_data] => 200/m-200 [title] => test-title )
```

how can i make it to only match: `m-200/test-title`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^m-([^/]+)/(?:.+?/)?([^/]+)/?$ ?til=data&id_data=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```